# Css or Javascript from CDN

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying out the bootstrap example from the wikipedia page and the code refers the bootstrap css via CDN as follows:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I am trying out the page in IE 9 and it works correctly only when  I add http: to the above link. I checked on the jquery page and their CDN links are also without http: Can anybody plz clear this issue? Thanks.

Comment: are you testing in local?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a URL starts with `//`, it means "relative to the current scheme". It's a quick and easy way to make sure it works properly whether you're using `http` or `https`.

However, I'm guessing you're viewing this HTML file on your own computer. The URL might be `file:///C:\Users\some_guy\Documents\test.html`

If this is the case, then the browser is suddenly looking for `file:///netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`, something that clearly does not exist.

You are correct that adding `http:` will fix it, but keep in mind that if you ever decide to upload your site somewhere and add https protection, you'll need to start fixing all links to CDN content.

Answer (score 0):

why you use "//", drop it and modify the address like: 
**"netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"**